# Proving that $m^*(E) = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}$

Let $E\subseteq \R.$ Assume that for any $x\in E,$ there exists $\delta_x > 0$ so that $$m^*(E\cap(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x))=0.$$ Prove that $m^*(E) = 0.$

$\textit{Proof.}$ Let $E$ be a finite set, say $E = \{a_1,\dots, a_k\} \subseteq \R.$ Then for every $\delta_x > 0, E\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^k I_i,$ where $I_i = (x_i-\delta_x,x_i+\delta_x).$ Hence $m^*(E) \le 2k\delta_x.$ Since it is true for every $\delta_x > 0, m^*(E) = 0.$

Next, suppose $E$ is a countably infinite set, say $E = \{x_i : i\in \N\}.$ Then taking $$I_n := (x_n - \frac{\delta_x}{2^{n+1}}, x_n + \frac{\delta_x}{2^{n+1}}),$$ we have $E\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\N} I_n$ so $$m^*(E) \le \sum_{n\in \N} \ell(I_n) = \sum_{n\in\N} (\frac{\delta_x}{2^n})\le \delta_x.$$ Since this is true for all $\delta_x > 0,$ we get $m^*(E) = 0,$ and we are done.

Can I please have feedback on my proof? Thanks!

Comment: The question doesn't say that $E$ is finite or countable. It could be uncountably infinite.

Comment: Makes sense that would be a problem. Hence, I'm stuck on how to prove this. @WhatsUp

Comment: Do you know about the regularity of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Not quite. I confuse it with the properties of outer measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable it has a countable base of open sets  $U_k$.

For each $x \in E$ we can find some $U_{k(x)}$ such that $x \in U_{k(x)} \subset (x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)$. Note that
$m^* (U_{k(x)} \cap E) = 0$.

Let $K = \{k(x) \}_{x \in E} \subset \mathbb{N}$, then $E = \cup_{k \in K} (E \cap U_k)$ and
$m^* E \le \sum_{k \in K} m^* (U_{k} \cap E) = 0$.

Comment: Is $(x_k - \delta_{x_k},x_k + \delta_{x_k})$ a cover of $[a,b]$ or $E \cap [a,b]$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Hmmm, my attempt at brevity introduced some sloppiness. Let me adjust... Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Is $U_{k(x)}$ open?

Comment: The $U_k$ form the countable base, so yes.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I see why you are asking, I have fixed a minor omission. I think I have more errors than sentences :-(.

Comment: Yes, $m^* U_{k(x)} = 0$ was the concern. Looks good to me now. +1

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thanks. I am annoyed that I could not get my compactness argument to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you have proved is that if $E$ is at most countable, then $m^*(E)=0.$ Although this is correct, this is not what the question asks.

The set $E$ in the problem can be uncountable. For each $x\in E,$ you have the open interval $I_{x}=(x-\delta_x, x+\delta_x)$ with the property that $m^*(I_{x}\cap E)=0.$ Note that $\{I_x:x\in E\}$ is an open cover of $E.$  Choose a countable subset $D$ of $E$ such that $E\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in D}I_x$ (Why can you do that?).

Since $E\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in D}(E\cap I_{x})$. Use the fact that $D$ Is countable and $m^*$ is countable subadditive to get that $M^*(E)\le \sum\limits_{x\in D} m^*(I_x\cap E)=0.$

Comment: Your (why?) is a good question. Why?

Comment: You mean why my (why?) is a good question? :P

Comment: No, I mean why is it true? (It is not.)

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing it out.